# Getting text input from the user and print it python using kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to print an input given by a user but all I get is: < ObjectProperty name=input >

I can't use Text Input in my py because python quits if I try to run a program with it installed. I have tried putting the popup in the 'test' class but it just comes up with a different error.

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you.

Here is my code:

In my py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class MyPopup(Popup):
    pass

class Test(Widget):
pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()

    def Process(self):
        text = MyPopup.input
        print(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

and in my kv:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MyPopup@Popup>
    input: text
    auto_dismiss: True
    size_hint: 0.4, 0.4
    TextInput:
        id: text
        hint_text: 'insert text'
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: app.Process()

<Test>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 0
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0, 0
            size: self.width, self.height - self.height/6
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 0.1
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0, 0
            size: self.width/2 + self.width/10, self.height - self.height/6
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0, self.height - self.height/6
            size: self.width, self.height/6

    Button:
        id: GL
        text: 'In here'
        pos: 0 , root.height - root.height/6
        on_parent: GLdropdown.dismiss()
        on_release: GLdropdown.open(self)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: root.height/6
        width: root.width/7
    DropDown:
        id: GLdropdown
        on_select: btn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])

        Button:
            id: 'AV'
            text: 'press me'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            on_release: Factory.MyPopup().open()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change:

```
on_text_validate: app.Process()
```

to:

```
on_text_validate: app.Process(self.text)
```

And change the `Process()` method to:

```
def Process(self, text):
    print(text)
```

I think it will work as you want.

The problem is that the line:

```
text = MyPopup.input
```

makes `text` a reference to the `ObjectProperty` of the class `MyPopup`. What you really want is a reference to the text of the `TextInput`, which is simply `self.text` in the `TextInput`.